# Adding binary integer without using + or -

Tags: c++, binary, bit-manipulation, bit

add two integers without using + or -.

This is my solution.

```
class Solution {
public:
    int getSum(int a, int b) {
        int temp=a & b; 
        a=a^b;
        while (temp>0){
            b=temp<<1; 
            temp=a & b; 
            a=a^b;
        }
        return a; 
    }
};
```

But it doesn't work on the cases when a=-12,
b=-8.

---

Compare it side by side with another people's working solution, he has:

```
class Solution {
public:
    int getSum(int a, int b) {
        int sum = a;

        while (b != 0)
        {
            sum = a ^ b;//calculate sum of a and b without thinking the carry 
            b = (a & b) << 1;//calculate the carry
            a = sum;//add sum(without carry) and carry
        }

        return sum;
    }
};
```

which is bascially the same. Why my solution doesn't work?

Comment: Because yours is wrong. The order and placement of the operations is significant.

Comment: I know I am wrong. But the code are basically the same

Comment: because `while (temp>0)` ... if you `&` 2 negative numbers, you get another negative

Comment: No, they're not *basically the same*. Read what I wrote again, specifically the second sentence. *abc* is not basically the same as *bac* or *cab* when you're reciting the alphabet.

Comment: if I change `while(temp<0)` to `while (temp != 0)` do you think this will work?

Answer (score 2):

Strictly speaking both your solution and the one you are comparing with are incorrect, unless you make specific assumptions about the representation of `signed`integral types.   The reason yours differs is order of operations.

The explanation is written in the C standard itself.  For example, from the 2011 ISO C standard (ISO/IEC 9899:2011) Section 6.5, para 4.

> Some operators (the unary operator ~ , and the binary operators <<, >>, &, ^, and |, collectively described as bitwise operators) shall have operands that have integral type. These operators return values that depend on the internal representations of integers, and thus have implementation-defined and undefined aspects for signed types.

These concerns hit home with expressions like `a & b` if either `a` or `b` is negative .... and your example has both.   `a << 1` gives a similar concern if `a` is negative.

To eliminate your problem, you need to work with `unsigned` values (for which bitwise operators have well defined behaviour).      If you need to deal with negative values, simply keep track of sign in another way (e.g. another variable of type `bool`).

In practice, bitwise operations work as expected for `signed` types with a twos-complement representation.  The problem with relying on that, however, is that an implementation is not required to use such a representation.